# How does Google Now work? Is Google cheating?

Tags: android, android-source, google-now

Google Now is apparently part of the Google Search app. It allows users to open the Google Now interface by swiping up from the home button on most devices. While swiping, users can see an overlaid circle with the name "Google".

My question is, how would I, your average Android app developer, be able to make something that acts just like Google Now? I haven't been able to find anything in the Android SDK that lets you do stuff like that. Is it a feature of Android that only Google and ROM developers can use (because it is part of core Android source)? If so, why is it "part of the Google Search app"?

Comment: This is part of the OS, not Google Now. You'd need to create your own ROM to accomplish it.

Comment: If you ask about `implementing the swipe up from home button`, I think it's really part of the OS. However, if you ask whether you can `change the app launched on swipe up`, it is possible to do that. Some apps in Play Store have achieved the latter.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question. The OP was curious how can this thing be done and I'd bet this is something many others would like to know as well. AFAIK "cheating" is not foul language, so what's wrong with this question?

Comment: This is legitimate question. Only because google develops unique features in the OS so it can be the only one that develops apps for it doesn't mean SO need to kiss their ass.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an activity with an intent filter of android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND, then when the user swipes up it will ask them what app to launch. If they click to launch your app by default then everytime they swipe up they'll open your app.